# Visual Studio Code PHP Inteliphense Formatting Brace On The Same Line With Statement

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I just hate formatting like this:

```
public function foo()
{
    // do the magic
}
```

I recently installed the PHP Inteliphense extension in VSCode especially for formatting. Exploring the extension settings I couldn't find any option related to formatiing except `Format enable/disable`.

Is there any possibility to fix this and to get the brace on the first line?

Comment: This is the PSR coding standards

Comment: @B001ᛦ But what about the fact that I don't care about that?

Comment: _..what about the fact that I don't care about that?..._ In that case I'm kind of sorry for your projects and the reviewer

Comment: @B001ᛦ Bad Luck! There is only one reviewer for my projects: me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree: K&R braces are the norm, and they're a *LIFESAVER* when it comes to long text extending over many lines.  The PSR 12 "coding standards" are just stupid :(

ANYWAY: check out Intellphense [issue#509](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/509) and [issue #730](https://github.com/bmewburn/vscode-intelephense/issues/730).

Once possible workaround (suggested in issue #509) might be .jsbeautifyrc.

FYI, I use phpfmt for Visual Studio Code.  It works great - including brace formatting :)

Comment: Thank you, I tried `phpfmt`, works great as you said, but with this ocasion I noticed that I was wrong in the first place, my bad, actually there is a setting especially for braces in PHP Intelliphense right above `enable/disable Format`: `Format braces, option k&r instead of psr12`.

Comment: I will accept your answer because dispite the fact that there is an option for k&r braces that is the only setting related to formatting, and I will disable formatting in `PHP Intelliphense` and use the `phpfmt` for that.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I was unclear from either either issue #509 or #730 whether or not Intellphense ever implemented K&R braces.  Clearly many users wanted it - I'm glad to see it actually happened :)  "Choice" is Good :)